# Can we pass some arguments/return value from VBscript function to Java Code

Tags: java, vbscript, sap-gui

I was able to pass arguments from Java to vbs. However I am unable to return the status of a function from vb script to my java code. Is there any way to do the same

From Java to VBS:

```
String strpath = "C:\\TEXTBOX.vbs";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript " + strpath + " " + OBJECT_Property +" "+OBJECT_Value );
```

Same as above the value or date from vbscript should be sent to java and I need to capture that data in my java code